# Android menu item text colour

Tags: android, text, colors, styles

I'm trying to change my list of menu item's (hardware button menu) font to white. Below is the code I currently have in my styles.xml..

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>

    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:panelBackground">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>

<style name ="MyPopupMenu" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

I know it doesn't contain anything at the minute that would attempt to change the colour, but that's because I removed it all after trying and failing using many different methods so I thought I'd gut it to show it as clean as possible.

I'm new to all this, still trying to get my head around it, so forgive me if it's a bit choppy. Anyway, other methods I've found online haven't seemed to work so could someone please throw me a bone? Just to be clear, I want the items in the menu that shows when the hardware button is clicked to be white text instead of black.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I changed the color of the menu item using this code hope this would help you:

```
 SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    text.append(getString(R.string.action_settings));
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_Manage);
    item1.setTitle(text);
```

Comment: First thing I've seen that actually works, although it's not the most ideal solution.. would prefer to do it in the style. It's the best so far though :)

Comment: I know it's not the ideal solution but it's the most clean one ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this in your styles

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: Where abouts? This is the problem I have been having, people saying "just throw this in".. not exactly sure where to put it :) I know in my styles obviously, but which part? In my AppTheme?

Comment: for which activity you are going to apply that style, for that you need to attach it.  In your case  in 'AppTheme' if you specifying in your MANIFEST like     <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" ..... >

Comment: If i put this line in `<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_dark</item>` it changes nothing..